# Replacing few values in a pandas dataframe column with another value

Tags: python, replace, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` as illustrated below:

```
BrandName Specialty
A          H
B          I
ABC        J
D          K
AB         L
```

I want to replace `'ABC'` and `'AB'` in column `BrandName` by `'A'`.
Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 191, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method on the column. The arguments are a list of the things you want to replace (here `['ABC', 'AB']`) and what you want to replace them with (the string `'A'` in this case):

```
>>> df['BrandName'].replace(['ABC', 'AB'], 'A')
0    A
1    B
2    A
3    D
4    A
```

This creates a new Series of values so you need to assign this new column to the correct column name:

```
df['BrandName'] = df['BrandName'].replace(['ABC', 'AB'], 'A')
```

Comment: One tricky thing if your datatypes are messed up in the dataframe (ie they look like strings but are not), use: df['BrandName'] = df['BrandName'].str.replace(['ABC', 'AB'], 'A')

Comment: I had to pass `inplace=True` as well, else it wasn't changing.

Comment: If you would like to extend this to an entire dataframe, it will be `df = df.replace(['ABC', 'AB'], 'A')`

Answer (score 52):

#### Replace

`DataFrame` object has powerful and flexible [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method:

```
DataFrame.replace(
        to_replace=None,
        value=None,
        inplace=False,
        limit=None,
        regex=False, 
        method='pad',
        axis=None)
```

Note, if you need to make changes in place, use `inplace` boolean argument for `replace` method:

#### Inplace

> **inplace**: boolean, default `False`
>   If `True`, in place. Note: this will modify any other views on this object (e.g. a column form a DataFrame). Returns the caller if this is `True`.

#### Snippet

```
df['BrandName'].replace(
    to_replace=['ABC', 'AB'],
    value='A',
    inplace=True
)
```

Comment: thanks for the snippet example, but it does not work. For one, if there is no = in the to_replace portion it errors out. For another, it is not making any replacements. Is there anyway to get a working example of the replace functionality in v 0.20.1?

Comment: Does `replace` not scale well? It seems to crash my machine when replacing ~5 million rows of integers. Any way around this?

Answer (score 20):

[`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html/%22loc%22) method can be used to replace multiple values:

```
df.loc[df['BrandName'].isin(['ABC', 'AB'])] = 'A'
```

Comment: This is faster than the replace method in my case.

Answer (score 18):

You could also pass a `dict` to the `pandas.replace` method:

```py
data.replace({
    'column_name': {
        'value_to_replace': 'replace_value_with_this'
    }
})
```

This has the advantage that you can replace **multiple values in multiple columns** at once, like so:

```py
data.replace({
    'column_name': {
        'value_to_replace': 'replace_value_with_this',
        'foo': 'bar',
        'spam': 'eggs'
    },
    'other_column_name': {
        'other_value_to_replace': 'other_replace_value_with_this'
    },
    ...
})
```

Answer (score 7):

This solution will change the existing dataframe itself:

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({"BrandName":["A", "B", "ABC", "D", "AB"], "Speciality":["H", "I", "J", "K", "L"]})
mydf["BrandName"].replace(["ABC", "AB"], "A", inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 5):

Just wanted to show that there is **no performance** difference between the 2 main ways of doing it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))

def loc():
    df1.loc[df1["A"] == 2] = 5
%timeit loc
19.9 ns ± 0.0873 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)


def replace():
    df2['A'].replace(
        to_replace=2,
        value=5,
        inplace=True
    )
%timeit replace
19.6 ns ± 0.509 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

Comment: using map might be faster though

Answer (score 4):

Created the Data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
dk=pd.DataFrame({"BrandName":['A','B','ABC','D','AB'],"Specialty":['H','I','J','K','L']})
```

Now use `DataFrame.replace()` function:

```
dk.BrandName.replace(to_replace=['ABC','AB'],value='A')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use loc for replacing based on condition and specifying the column name

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['A','H'],['B','I'],['ABC','ABC'],['D','K'],['AB','L']],columns=['BrandName','Col2'])
df.loc[df['BrandName'].isin(['ABC', 'AB']),'BrandName'] = 'A'
```

Output 
[image]