# How to implement KNN in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, knn

I wanted to implement KNN in python. Till now I have loaded my data into Pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
train_df = pd.read_csv("creditlimit_train.csv") # train dataset
train_df.head()
```

The output of head is

```
SNo      Salary      LoanAmt   Level
101      100000      10000     Low Level
102      108500      11176     Low Level
103      125500      13303     Low Level
104      134000      14606     Low Level
105      142500      15960     Low Level


test_df = pd.read_csv("creditlimit_test.csv")
test_df.head()
```

The output of head is

```
SNo      Salary      LoanAmt   Level
101      100000      10000     Low Level
102      108500      11176     Low Level
103      125500      13303     Low Level
104      134000      14606     Low Level
105      142500      15960     Low Level

neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5,algorithm='auto')
predictor_features = ['Salary','LoanAmt']
dependent_features = ['Level']
neigh.fit(train_df[predictor_features],train_df[dependent_features])
```

**How do I use the fit function to use salary,loanAmt as predictor to predict the levels for my test_df?**

Update 1: The levels are 3 : Low, Medium and High

Comment: You should probably try looking at the sklearn API. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your DataFrame to a numpy array and pass as input

```
# convert class labels in numerical data, assuming you have two classes
df['Level'].replace(['Low Level'],0)
df['Level'].replace(['High Level'],1)

# extra data and class labels
data = df[['Salary','LoanAmt']]
target = df['Level']

# convert df to numpy arrays
data = data.values
target =  target.values

# you would ideally want to do a test train split.
#Train the model on training data and test on the test data for accuracy

#pass in fit function
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5,algorithm='auto')
neigh.fit(data,target) ## how to passs the parameters here?
```

Some useful links:

[Convert pandas dataframe to numpy array, preserving index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13187778/convert-pandas-dataframe-to-numpy-array-preserving-index)

[Replacing few values in a pandas dataframe column with another value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060098/replacing-few-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column-with-another-value)

[Selecting columns in a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11285613/selecting-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think that is going to help me for sure :)
Yuvraj bhai, I am looking for something to compare my data of train with the test.
Data is almost same with some entries purposefully changed to be tested. How can I compare tow different datasets?

Comment: What data do you want to compare? If you want to check how well your model has predicted, please see http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html

Comment: Glad to be of help