# How to split a string in a column within a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is an example of the file I have,

```
Name     Att1     Att2     Att3
AB_EN    1        2        3
CD       5        6        7
FG_EN    7        8        9
```

So, in the column 'Name', where '_EN' is present, I want to remove the '_EN' part. The output should be as follows:

```
Name     Att1     Att2     Att3
AB       1        2        3
CD       5        6        7
FG       7        8        9
```

This is what I was trying:

```
name = df['Name']

for entry in name:
    if "_EN" in entry:
       entry = entry.split('_')[0]
```

However, this is not working. What is a good way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing few values in a pandas dataframe column with another value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060098/replacing-few-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column-with-another-value)

Comment: several duplicates are around: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58303305/replacing-few-values-in-a-column-based-on-a-list-in-python

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060098/replacing-few-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column-with-another-value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["AB_EN", "CD", "FG_EN"]})
df['Name'] = df['Name'].str.split("_").str[0]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
  Name
0   AB
1   CD
2   FG
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [string methods of the pandas Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html)

In your case that would be

```
df['Name']=(df.Name
      .str.split('_')  # split on _
      .str[0] # Only keep first part of the split
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
df['Name'] = [name.split('_')[0] for name in df['Name']]
```

You just have to make the changes in place to the series in your dataframe.