# inf values while division of column A by column B

Tags: python

I am doing division of column A by column B. Certain places where denominator is 0, I get inf values. How do I replace these inf values with 1 from column C?

```
Df['C'] = Df['A'] / Df['B']
```

Comment: You want to remove the whole row, or replace the infinity with something else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replacing few values in a pandas dataframe column with another value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060098/replacing-few-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column-with-another-value)

Comment: Thanks Baby Desta. Your comment was helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
import numpy as np
Df = Df[Df.C != np.inf]
```

**Edit:**

To replace all `np.inf` values by 1, use this code:

```
Df.loc[Df.C == np.inf] = 1
```

Alternatively, you can use [`pandas.DataFrame.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) method like this:

```
Df['C'] = Df['C'].replace({np.inf: 1})
```

Comment: My apologies, I dont want to delete all the rows ith inf value, rather replace it with value 1

Answer (score 0):

```py
df['C'] = df['A'].div(df['B']) # div will replace inf with null
filt = df['C'].notna() # a filter for not null
df = df.loc[filt] # the new dataframe with no null
```

Comment: My apologies, I dont want to delete all the rows ith inf value, rather replace it with value 1