# Replacing values in pandas data frame with None

Tags: python, pandas

This thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060098/replacing-few-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column-with-another-value) shows `replace` with `inplace=True` to change values in pandas data frame.

I want to apply the same technique, but replacing with `None`

```
mydf = pd.DataFrame({"col1":[5, 5, 8, 4, 5], "col2":[2, 5, 6, 7, 5]})
mydf.replace([5], None, inplace=True)
```

`mydf` changes like this and there is an additional output

```
   col1  col2
0     5     2
1     5     2
2     8     6
3     4     7
4     4     7
```

```
col1    None
col2    None
dtype: object
```

How to replace values with `None`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prefer use `pd.NA` rather than `None`. [Read this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/missing_data.html)

```
mydf.replace([5], pd.NA, inplace=True)
# mydf.replace([5], [None], inplace=True)
```

```
>>> mydf
   col1  col2
0  <NA>     2
1  <NA>  <NA>
2     8     6
3     4     7
4  <NA>  <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

`None` also happens to be the [default value](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) for `value` argument so if you need to use it, you can place it in a 1-element list to distinguish that you're not passing the default:

```
mydf = mydf.replace([5], [None])
```

also: `inplace=True` is [not so good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59242208/9332187), opt for assigning back