# How do I change the same string within a column and make it permanent using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to change the Strings "SLL" under the competitions column to "League" but when i tried this:

```
messi_dataset.replace("SLL", "League",regex = True)
```

It only changed the first "SLL" to "League" but then other strings that were "SLL" became "UCL. I have no idea why. I also tried changing regex = True to inlace = True but no luck.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ldq6o70j-FsjX832GbYq24jzeR0IwlEs/view?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OeCSutkfdHdroCmTEG9KqnYypso3bwDm/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: Put the relevant code here, not links to Google Drive.

Comment: Yes the code I used is:  messi_dataset.replace("SLL", "League",regex = True) What other code is relevant that should be included?

Comment: messi_dataset it is the main data set with columns or it is  just a  pandas series

Comment: @GeorgeZambrano you should attach a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Please see this guide for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a dataframe as below:

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({'Competitions': ['SLL', 'sll','apple', 'banana', 'aabbSLL', 'ccddSLL']})

# write a regex pattern that replaces 'SLL' 
# I assumed case-irrelevant

regex_pat = re.compile(r'SLL', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
df['Competitions'].str.replace(regex_pat, 'league', regex=True)

#   Input DataFrame
    Competitions
0   SLL
1   sll
2   apple
3   banana
4   aabbSLL
5   ccddSLL

Output:

0        league
1        league
2         apple
3        banana
4    aabbleague
5    ccddleague
Name: Competitions, dtype: object
```

Hope it clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

base on this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27060328/4817807) test this code:

```
messi_dataset['competitions'] = messi_dataset['competitions'].replace("SLL", "League")
```

also, there are many different ways to do this like this one that I test:

```
messi_dataset.replace({'competitions': 'SLL'}, "League")
```

for those cases that 'SLL' is a part of another word:

```
messi_dataset.replace({'competitions': 'SLL'}, "League", regex=True)
```

Comment: PERFECT IT WORKED!