# How to quickly fillna with a sequence

Tags: python, pandas

I have a question about how to quickly fillna with a sequence in Python(pandas).I have a dataset like following(the true dataset is longer),

| Time | Number |
| --- | --- |
| t0 | NA |
| t1 | NA |
| t2 | NA |
| t3 | 0 |
| t4 | NA |
| t5 | NA |
| t6 | NA |
| t7 | NA |
| t8 | 0 |
| t9 | NA |

My requirement is to add numbers to N lines before and after non-blank lines, and the sequence range is range(-N,N+1).The interval between any two non-empty rows in the dataset is greater than C(constant), our N will be less than C, so there is no need to consider the coverage problem for the time being. Assuming N=2, the result I need is as follows :

| Time | Number |
| --- | --- |
| t0 | NA |
| t1 | -2 |
| t2 | -1 |
| t3 | 0 |
| t4 | 1 |
| t5 | 2 |
| t6 | -2 |
| t7 | -1 |
| t8 | 0 |
| t9 | 1 |

At present, the only way I can think of is to use a loop, but the efficiency is low. Does pandas have such a method to do it quickly?

Comment: do you have a list of values you want to put in the place of the na values ?

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27060098/replacing-few-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column-with-another-value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are still some unknowns in your question, like what happens if the intervals overlap. Here I will consider that a further interval overwrites the previous one (you can do the other way around with a change of code, see second part).

Using `rolling`, `groupby.cumcount`, and a `mask`:

```
s = df['Number'].notna().shift(-N, fill_value=False)
m = s.rolling(2*N+1, min_periods=1).max().astype(bool)

df['Number2'] = df.groupby(s.cumsum()).cumcount().sub(N).where(m)
```

*NB. I used a slightly different example to show the overlap.*

output:

```
   Time  Number  Number2
 0   t0     NaN      NaN
 1   t1     NaN     -2.0
 2   t2     NaN     -1.0
 3   t3     0.0      0.0
 4   t4     NaN      1.0
 5   t5     NaN     -2.0  # here we have an overlap, use latter value
 6   t6     NaN     -1.0
 7   t7     0.0      0.0
 8   t8     NaN      1.0
 9   t9     NaN      2.0
10  t10     NaN      NaN
```

##### priority on first group

```
s = df['Number'].notna().shift(N, fill_value=False)[::-1]
m = s.rolling(2*N+1, min_periods=1).max().astype(bool)

df['Number3'] = df.groupby(s.cumsum()).cumcount(ascending=False).rsub(N).where(m)
```

output:

```
   Time  Number  Number2  Number3
0    t0     NaN      NaN      NaN
1    t1     NaN     -2.0     -2.0
2    t2     NaN     -1.0     -1.0
3    t3     0.0      0.0      0.0
4    t4     NaN      1.0      1.0
5    t5     NaN     -2.0      2.0  # difference in behavior
6    t6     NaN     -1.0     -1.0
7    t7     0.0      0.0      0.0
8    t8     NaN      1.0      1.0
9    t9     NaN      2.0      2.0
10  t10     NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your results are pretty close to what I want, but there seems to be some inconsistency in the last two lines.

Comment: @Lucio updated, I had forgotten a fill_value for shift ;)

Comment: Thankyou very much. I will try to study your code. They are powerful.

Answer (score 0):

```
def function1(dd:pd.DataFrame):
    if dd.iloc[2,1]==0:
        df1.loc[dd.index,'Number']=range(-2,len(dd)-2)

n=2
pd.Series(df1.rolling(2*(n+1),center=True)).apply(function1).pipe(lambda dd:df1)
        
        output
        
             Time  Number
            0   t0     NaN
            1   t1    -2.0
            2   t2    -1.0
            3   t3     0.0
            4   t4     1.0
            5   t5     2.0
            6   t6    -2.0
            7   t7    -1.0
            8   t8     0.0
            9   t9     1.0
```

Answer (score -1):

Could we have a bit more information, please?

I notice in your end result `t0` is still NA, why is that? Do you still want to keep some values as NaN?

In the example, `t3` was `0` originally, and in the result it was still `0`, which made sense within the sequence. But what if it was already populated, and not with `0` but another value like `5`? Would you want to keep the `5` or assign the `0` from the sequence in that position? And if you kept the `5`, would then `t4` be `0`?

Here's a few solutions just in case:

### To fill in the NaN values with a sequence (skipping populated values)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Time': 't0', 'Number': None},
    {'Time': 't1', 'Number': None},
    {'Time': 't2', 'Number': None},
    {'Time': 't3', 'Number': 0},
    {'Time': 't4', 'Number': None},
    {'Time': 't5', 'Number': None},
])

len_null = df['Number'].isna().sum()
starting_number = -2

df.loc[df['Number'].isna(), 'Number'] = list(range(starting_number, len_null-abs(starting_number)))

print(df)
```

Will give you this:

```
  Time  Number
0   t0    -2.0
1   t1    -1.0
2   t2     0.0
3   t3     0.0
4   t4     1.0
5   t5     2.0
```

### To fill in the entire column with a sequence (overwriting populated values)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Time': 't0', 'Number': None},
    {'Time': 't1', 'Number': None},
    {'Time': 't2', 'Number': None},
    {'Time': 't3', 'Number': 0},
    {'Time': 't4', 'Number': None},
    {'Time': 't5', 'Number': None},
])

starting_number = -2
df['Number'] = list(range(starting_number, len(df)-abs(starting_number)))
print(df)
```

Will give you:

```
  Time  Number
0   t0      -2
1   t1      -1
2   t2       0
3   t3       1
4   t4       2
5   t5       3
```

### To fill in the NAN values with a sequence (skipping the sequence where values are populated)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([
    {'Time': 't0', 'Number': None},
    {'Time': 't1', 'Number': None},
    {'Time': 't2', 'Number': None},
    {'Time': 't3', 'Number': 0},
    {'Time': 't4', 'Number': None},
    {'Time': 't5', 'Number': None},
])

starting_number = -2
new_series = pd.Series(list(range(starting_number, len(df)-abs(starting_number))))
df['Number'] = df['Number'].fillna(new_series)
print(df)
```

Will give you:

```
  Time  Number
0   t0    -2.0
1   t1    -1.0
2   t2     0.0
3   t3     0.0
4   t4     2.0
5   t5     3.0
```

(Notice that `1` would have gone into the `t3` slot, but since there was a `0` there already, it just skipped it)